# Why is my file pointer causing an undefined symbol error?

Tags: c

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[50];   /* for holding file's name  */
    FILE *fp;            /* fp is the "file pointer" */

    printf("Please enter the name of an input file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    if (!(fp = fopen(filename, "w")))    /*w=write*/
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file\a\n");
    else {/* process file */
            fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The line

```
FILE *fp; 
//is giving me an error Undefined Symbol "FILE"
```

The line

```
fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file\a\n"); 
//is giving me an error Undefined Symbol "stderr"
```

I thought these keywords were standard C/C++? Why are they giving me errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you `#include <stdio.h>`? Also your declaration of `main()` is incorrect. It should return `int`, not `void`.

And no, `FILE` is not a keyword in either C or C++. Its declaration is in `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: I forgot to include stdio. Now my error is undefined function 'fopen'. But this is declared in stdio.h

Comment: @theIrishUser: Yes, fopen is in stdio.h. Are you absolutely positive that you get an undefined function fopen? Please edit your question with the complete program you have so far with the exact error message

Comment: My error is now, 'fopen' is not a member of 'std'. Just edited the code above

Comment: Ok, I checked the source code to my stdio.h and the fopen declaration was commented out. No idea why, I only started using this compiler and never touched a thing. Its all working fine now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following line as your 1st statement in your file

`#include <stdio.h>`

The datatype FILE and functions such as fprint() are defined in this header file and hence you would need that to run your program (tell the compiler the definition of FILE, fprintf() etc)

Comment: Not to be picky, but `#include <stdio.h>` is not a statement, it's a preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Visual Studio Code (version 1.67.1) because my `c_cpp_properties.json` had the "compilerPath" set to "cl.exe", but my `tasks.json` had "command" set to "clang.exe".

I resolved my issue by copying the path to clang.exe from "command" in `tasks.json`, and using that for the "compilerPath" value in `c_cpp_properties.json`.